# Flex child inside inline-block parent - IE11 can't handle the layout alignment

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, cross-browser

The following piece of code behaves differently on IE11. It's like the anchor tag is being pushed up, something seems to be not quite ok with the vertical alignment

```
   <a href="www.mysite.com" style={{display: 'inline-block'}}>
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>Text inside wrapper</div>
   </a>
   <span>Blah blhsdf ksdhf sksfh</span>
```

Chrome/Other browsers

[image]

IE11

[image]

Comment: inline-block elements might require a vertical-align reset : https://jsbin.com/racuvomove/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 0):

Agree with G-Cyrillus, try to modify your code as below (add [vertial-align css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/vertical-align)):

```
   <a href="www.mysite.com" style={{display: 'inline-block'; vertical-align:'top';}}>
      <div style={{display: 'flex'}}>Text inside wrapper</div>
   </a>
   <span>Blah blhsdf ksdhf sksfh</span>
```

IE 11 result:

[image]